# run option is disabled for my react native project in android studio

Tags: android, react-native

I made a new react native project.

According to this link `https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup`

In the document
they start the application by running this command

`npx react-native run-android`

Its working fine on my machine, I mean the app is running.

But what I want to do is run the app without command.
I open the android folder in the androidStudio.

In the androidStudio, the run icon is disabled and importing 'android' cradle is not finished.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add configuration for this to executed directly from Android studio. Select the app and re-import the project.